# I can not inject Map<String, String> from YAML file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have this properties in my YAML file:

```
request-topic:
  topics:
    IMPORT_CHARGES: topic-name-1
    IMPORT_PAYMENTS: topic-name-2
    IMPORT_CATALOGS: topic-name-3
```

And this class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "topic-properties")
public class TopicProperties {
    private Map<String, String> topics = new HashMap<>();

    public String getTopicNameByType(String type){
        return topics.get(type);
    }
}
```

But when I autowire this properies I get empty Map:

```
@Service
public class TopicRouterImpl implements TopicRouter {

    private final TopicProperties topics;

    public TopicRouterImpl(TopicProperties topics) {
        this.topics = topics;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        topics.getTopicNameByType("IMPORT_CHARGES");
    }

    @Override
    public String getTopicName(MessageType messageType) {
        return topics.getTopicNameByType(messageType.name());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the name mismatch in your yaml file it should be equals to the specified prefix : `topic-properties`. Like this :

```
topic-properties:
  topics:
    IMPORT_CHARGES: topic-name-1
    IMPORT_PAYMENTS: topic-name-2
    IMPORT_CATALOGS: topic-name-3
```